# No puedo instalar una maquina virtual (virtualbox) en linux debian. alguien sabe por que puede ser?

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, descarga, gpg

Intento instalar VBox en debian linux, usando el comando apt search virtualbox no me surgen opciones de descarga de la aplicacion, solo me sale una opcion q es *libvirt0* el cual no me deja descargar tampoco; luego de ello intente ingresar algunas de las apt-key que ofrece la pagina de virtualbox pero me sale el error = "gpg: no se han encontrados datos OpenPGP validos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar esta serie de pasos, debería funcionarte bien en la última versión de debian:

```
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0
```

Fuente: [Vitux](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-debian-10/)

Comment: intente con el primer comando:
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -   
y me salta este error:
gpg: no se han encotrados datos OpenPGP validos.